# What cellular network is used for automobile theft recovery? Can that be used for PCs and mobile devices?

Tags: mobile, physical, wireless

I'm interested in sending a remote wipe command to stolen IT devices, such as a cell phone, or wifi connected device.  However most remote wipe technologies require that the cellular service (or wifi) be connected in order to receive the command.

This requirement is self-defeating since the Wifi device will most definitely be out of range by the time the command is issued, and the cellular plan may changed before a impatient end user requires inbound calls to work on their replacement SIM card.

- What set of technologies is used in automobile recovery?  (Is it still MobiTex?)
- Is it possible to re-purpose the cellular technology used for Automobile theft tracking for PCs, cell phones, and BYOD devices?
- What is the ideal set of technologies (low power draw, broad coverage) that would best enable this low bandwidth application?

Comment: SatPhone/Sat Internet connection if you're really worried. Hook it up to the car immobilizer. Wait til they drive out into the middle of nowhere and BAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobiTex is still in use. As far as I recall (at least in EU) the frequencies are lower than "regular mobile frequencies" and hence the coverage is much better. Also, a lot of companies offer a combination of GPS and GSM/GPRS units to track and send/receive commands.

It's possible to re-use the cellular tech used for theft tracking for any device that can signal, e.g., take the iOS features, but obviously you'd either have to trust that devices signalling capabilities or add hardware to it.